# Button long click

Tags: c#, winforms, stopwatch

I have a timer developed with c# and WinForms controlled by an external button
when I press the button, the time starts, this is the main action! I would like to know
if is it possible to recognize a long press in this button so I can program the action to stop
I am very new to C#, by programming language side is it possible to recognize this long press?

Comment: It would be very helpful to show us some of your code that starts or stops the timer. Regarding your question, you could go with the `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events of the button.

Comment: I've been reading about that and it seems to me that this is only when I use the mouse to click on a button, right???? my timer is controlled for an external button connected to the PC. Does that still work?

Comment: Without knowing what signals you get from the interface for this external button it is impossible to say, but does it provide something like they `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` events you get from a normal keyboard?

Comment: I would say that it is the same, but I won't be using any key on the keyboard or the mouse itself if that's what you mean. This external button communicates with the interface trough a DLL provided by the company who developed the device with the button

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

create a public datetime variable and add button_mousedown and button_mouseup event to your form.

put the following code in there:

```
    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dt = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var diff= ( DateTime.Now-dt).TotalMilliseconds;
        
        if(diff > x) // x is the minimum time you want the mouse to be down on the button
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
```

when you do a click on the button, the exact time is stored in the "dt" variable.
when the click is over, the mouseup event is triggered and there you can compare the time, when you pressed the button with the currenttime and you can get a difference in milliseconds with my code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the button `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events.
Here is one way to create a counter with textbox and button with "Long Press" event:

```
private bool IsTargetButtonClicked = false;
private Timer HoldButtonTimer;
private void TargerButton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    IsTargetButtonClicked = false;
}

private void TargerButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    IsTargetButtonClicked = true;
    InitHoldButtonTimer();
}


private void InitHoldButtonTimer()
{           
    if (HoldButtonTimer == null)
    {
        HoldButtonTimer = new Timer();
        HoldButtonTimer.Interval = 100;
        HoldButtonTimer.Tick += HoldButtonTimer_Tick;
    }

    HoldButtonTimer.Start();           
}


private int SomeIntValueToAdvance = 0;
private void HoldButtonTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsTargetButtonClicked)
    {
        SomeIntValueToAdvance++;

        textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            textBox1.Text = SomeIntValueToAdvance.ToString();
        }));
    }
    else
    {
        KillHoldButtonTimer();
    }
}

private void KillHoldButtonTimer()
{           
    if (HoldButtonTimer == null)
    {
        HoldButtonTimer.Tick -= HoldButtonTimer_Tick;
        HoldButtonTimer.Stop();
        HoldButtonTimer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: That is really helpful but I won't be using any key on the keyboard or the mouse. It is an external button connected to a device and the device is connected to the PC. My program communicates with this device through a DLL. Does that still work?

Comment: It's the principles of achieving this effect, I don't know what events your DLL has, but maybe there are events with similar behavior, but I don't know what is the device and what are its events.